# Strange CSS drop-shadow bug in Chrome only?

Tags: css, dropshadow

Seeing a very strange glitch with a large drop shadow on a site that is in development. Only seems to happen in Chrome. Glitch will disappear and reappear as window is re-sized.

url: https://w3stage.com/pok/order/

img: [drop shadow issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RadYR.jpg)

css:

```
.set-container {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    box-shadow: 0 70px 70px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

edit: i am on macOS, Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Can't reproduce `Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) Win8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the same result in specific window sizes.

I played around a little bit and what seemed to cancel this issue was removing the `border-radius` definition from the `.set-container` class definition.

I am not sure why it worked, but I have seen in my experience that shadows and border-radiuses sometimes have issues. You could consider restructuring that part or just removing the border-radius.

Just as additional info, I was able to reproduce the issue on:

> Chrome 83.0.4103.61 (64-bit)
>
> Window size: `936 <= Width < 1200` and `701 < Height < 763`.

I am not sure if there's something specific about those dimensions in your case, but that's where I seem to get the extra shadow.

**UPDATE**

I did test something else that does not have issues (as far as I am aware) with the border-radius.

I switched from `box-shadow` to `filter: drop-shadow`. The end result is this line:

```
filter: drop-shadow(0 70px 70px black);
```

It looks a little bit different than the box-shadow rule, but does the trick and doesn't have issues with the border-radius.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to fix it. Not my call on the design, but i can at least show it to them now.

Comment: @Phil I added a different option you could use instead of `box-shadow`. As far as I tested it doesn't have issues with the `border-radius`. Please check it and let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this aberration in Chrome v86 on a PC and in Chrome v86 on an iPad.  I found that I could reliably make the effect half as large (huh?) by eliminating `overflow: hidden` from the parent div to my image (which has the drop shadow).